# Waiting until all processes end to execute next line in Bash

Tags: bash

In a script I'm writing right now, I create many background processes in attempts to run my script on multiple devices in parallel. This functionality works, but it would appear I have no control of it. The simple `wait` command does not get me the results I need.

Abridged code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ""

date

echo ""
echo "Displaying devices to be configured:"
./adb devices | sed "1d ; $ d"
echo ""
echo "###########################"
echo "#                         #"
echo "# Starting configuration! #"
echo "#                         #"
echo "###########################"
echo ""

# All commands ran through this function
DeviceConfig () {
  ...
  # Large list of commands
  ...
}

# This is the loop that spawns all the processes. Note the ampersand I'm using.
for usb in $(./adb devices -l | awk '/ device usb:/{print $3}'); do ( DeviceConfig & ) ; done

echo ""
echo "###########################"
echo "#                         #"
echo "# Configuration complete! #"
echo "#                         #"
echo "###########################"
```

While this will successfully run all my commands in parallel, my output is not as intended.

Actual output:

```
Wed Oct  5 13:11:26 EDT 2016

Displaying devices to be configured:
3100c2759da2a200    device
3100c2ddbbafa200    device

###########################
#                         #
# Starting configuration! #
#                         #
###########################


###########################
#                         #
# Configuration complete! #
#                         #
###########################

Starting: Intent { cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings }
Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings }
Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
...
```

(The `...` is to imply more output from the script.)

Putting a `wait` in the loop does not solve the issue. Putting a `wait` after the loop does not solve the issue. How do I write this loop so the configurations happen in between the `Starting configuration!` and `Configuration complete!` output?

Comment: BTW -- [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor); that makes the contents of `IFS` and your glob-related shell configuration modify how your logic behaves. Better to follow a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop to iterate over an input stream line-by-line.

Comment: To keep things completely unambiguous, I'd also make it `pids+=( "$!" )` -- if you had, say, `IFS=0`, then `pids+=( $! )` would make the single value `1034` add two separate array elements, `1` and `34`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask `wait` to wait on multiple processes, e.g.:

```
pids=()

for usb in $(./adb devices -l | awk '/ device usb:/{print $3}'); do DeviceConfig & pids+=($!); done

wait "${pids[@]}"
```

Comment: ...or not pass any arguments at all, in which case waiting for *all* background jobs is default behavior.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Even better, didn't realize that but I see it in the help text now :)

Comment: Best solution. Worked.